# Magento 2: How to find which config causing error "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" when trying to serialize checkout config

Tags: php, magento, utf-8, magento2

I'm on Magneto 2.3.4. In `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml` there's a line like this:

```
        window.checkoutConfig = <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;
```

Following the function, it comes down to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage.php::getSerializedCheckoutConfig()`

And the serialize function is in `vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/JsonHexTag.php`

I added `json_last_error_msg()` to the exception message, and basically the error message is now:

```
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): 
Unable to serialize value. Error:Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

How to quickly find the checkout configuration value or key that is having malformed UTF-8 characters? Or how to quickly fix this in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to debug and find the problematic character thanks to a suggestion on Magento StackExchange.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305931/magento-2-how-to-find-which-config-causing-error-malformed-utf-8-characters-p

Basically using XDebug to debug the key and value being processed using a utf8 check:

```
mb_detect_encoding($suspiciousString, 'UTF-8', true)
```

It turned out to be a wrong crypt key that i was having that decrypted some of the credentials into malformed characters